# Play Framework Unicode symbols in HTTP Header

Tags: java, scala, unicode, playframework

I have weird trouble with unicode characters in HTTP Header.
I've send "å" (\U00E5) but in `request.headers` i got \UFFE5 character.
This behavior is similar for all escaped characters.

How this could be?

Comment: Non-ASCII characters don't work in HTTP headers in general. RFC 5987 will fix some of this this (specifically header parameters) when it is more widely supported, but for today avoid it.